# How to debug Strapi in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, strapi

How can I debug Strapi project in WebStorm? (https://strapi.io/)

[image: what should I do here??]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you like to debug your controllers, etc., you have to start the server in debug mode, using `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js dev`, like

[image]

and then open the corresponding URL in browser

[image]

Comment: Do you know, how can I debug strapi in develop mode? (`strapi start`?)